# Init.d code not quite working

Tags: bash, init.d

The filtered out data from a MQTT live stream is dumped into a csv file named `mqtt.csv` and the dumping process is done by `executor_start_up_job.txt` which is written in BASH (has a shebang).

I want to make the dumping of the filter daemon, i.e. in the background, and also want to make it in so that every time the system is rebooted it is done automatically. So I've concluded to write an init.d script, and contents of my code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

requested_command=$1

start() {

        /home/ed/start_up_job/executor_start_up_job.txt &
}
# Restart the Dump
stop() {

        killproc executor_start_up_job.txt
        echo
}
### main logic ###
case $requested_command in
  start)
        start
        ;;
  stop)
        stop
        ;;
  status)
        last_line=`cat mqtt.csv | tail -1`
        echo "last print line: $last_line"
        ;;
  restart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Once I have inserted `set -x` I get the following output:

```
+ ./MySQL_table_update_daemon.sh start
+ requested_command=start
+ start
+ exit 0
```

**Q:** If I can make this code to work, then I will place it into the `/etc/init.d/` directory, so that it can work every time. However currently it does not work and the output without the `set -x` the is nothing i.e it's as if I've just pushed enter in the terminal.

Comment: Added an answer, check it and if it works click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "I accept the answer"

Comment: For `status)`, it would be better to use `echo -n 'last print line: '; tail -n 1 mqtt.csv`, which eliminates the [useless use of `cat`](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#cat) and the redirection to a shell variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `exit 0` at the end of the script, otherwise it will quit everytime it is run.

You can check out `cat /etc/init.d/skeleton` for an exemple of a working init.d script. (Probably overkill for what you want to do, but it can help with a few things).